# how can I create text file using cfml

Tags: cffile

How to generate text file using **ColdFusion** web development, 
and how can I perform **write,update,delete** actions.

Comment: May this url might help you [http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2027-reading-in-file-data-using-coldfusion-8-s-new-file-functions.htm]